# Full page as/plus Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I want to have a page which is a full blown page i.e. I can call it with URL like this for example :

```
/path/to/client/33
```

but then I want to be able to call/render it from another page i.e. (pseudo code)

```
/path/to/customer/678
...find client id.....
render :client, :id => 33 #inside the customer page
render :customer
```

I understand that I can do it like partial, what I can't figure out is how to pass parameters between them.
I was thinking of layout also, but then how do I arrange for the customer controller to be first to run? So that I can find the client ID and then render client.
Think of a customer as one entity "having" many clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# app/views/your_controller/_client.html.erb
The Client is <%= client.name %>

# app/views/your_controller/customer.html.erb
The Customer is <%= @customer.name %>
<%= render :partial => 'client', :locals => { :client => @client } %>

# app/views/your_controller/client.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'client', :locals => { :client => @client } %>

# your_controller.rb
def customer
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @client = @customer.client
end

def client
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  # i forget if you need to assign it client to make the partial work
  client = @client
end
```

Comment: thanx...one additional question though.. I want to pass the client_id (and client controller to do its work) not the @client obj.

Comment: I don't follow your question, but I will offer this. A good design principle is thin controllers, fat models. if you are merely looking to pass the client id instead of the object, then you can modify the above code to do just that. in the view, you would have <%= client_id %> and in the controller you would set the client_id to the params[:id]. Good luck!

Comment: thanx, Let me rephrase it ... I can pass the client_id, but if the client information is displayed before the customer information how do I force the customer to be executed first, so that it can acquire the info OR that is exactly what will happen because I use /customer/333. Will try tomorrow..10x

Comment: hmm.. does not seem to work.
The purpose of partial seems to be just rendering partial template.
What I'm trying to do is initiate internal call to a diff URL (mimicking separate request) get the response-data and integrate it into the current template-rendering.
So that the Client part can live and be called as separate entity and also be integrated in other controllers output (Customer)

Comment: either I am not understanding what you are trying to do or you are not understanding what you can do with Rails. You shouldn't need to make a separate request just to keep "the Client part" as a separate entity. You have access to that model, or any model as it happens, from your Customer controller. In the spirit of trying to answer the actual question, you could use the [rest-client gem](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) to make the request you want to the client controller and then use the response in your Customer page.